# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'op'

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am have a time series data and I am trying to build and train an LSTM model over it. I have 1 input and 1 Output corresponding to my model. I am trying to build a Many to Many model where Input length is exactly equal to output length.

The shape of my inputs are

```
print(np.shape(X)) 
(1700,70,401) 
#(examples, Timestep, Features)
```

Shape of my output is

```
print(np.shape(Y_1)) 
(1700,70,3) 
#(examples, Timestep, Features)
```

Now When I am trying to approach this problem via sequential API everything is running fine.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(70,401), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(3,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01),loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy())
model.fit(X, Y_1, epochs=2,verbose=1)
```

But When I am approaching it from the functional API approach then it is showing the error

***AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'op'***

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(70,401))
hidden = LSTM(32,return_sequences=True)(input_layer)
output_1 = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(hidden)
# output_2 = Dense(np.shape(Y_2)[2], activation='softmax')(hidden)
model_lstm = Model(inputs=X, outputs = Y_1)
```

My question is How do I resolve the error?

I can not use the sequential API to solve the problem because I want to use Multiple Outputs to train i.e. I have 2 different outputs on which I want to train(But for the scope of this question let's just assume I have one set of input and one set of output)!!

The Entire error that I am getting is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-df3a5a1656f0> in <module>
----> 1 model_lstm = Model(X,  Y_1)

/root/anaconda3/envs/TensorPy36/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    144 
    145   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 146     super(Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    147     _keras_api_gauge.get_cell('model').set(True)
    148     # initializing _distribution_strategy here since it is possible to call

/root/anaconda3/envs/TensorPy36/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    165         'inputs' in kwargs and 'outputs' in kwargs):
    166       # Graph network
--> 167       self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
    168     else:
    169       # Subclassed network

/root/anaconda3/envs/TensorPy36/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    456     try:
--> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    458     finally:
    459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/root/anaconda3/envs/TensorPy36/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in _init_graph_network(self, inputs, outputs, name, **kwargs)
    268 
    269     if any(not hasattr(tensor, '_keras_history') for tensor in self.outputs):
--> 270       base_layer_utils.create_keras_history(self._nested_outputs)
    271 
    272     self._base_init(name=name, **kwargs)

/root/anaconda3/envs/TensorPy36/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py in create_keras_history(tensors)
    182     keras_tensors: The Tensors found that came from a Keras Layer.
    183   """
--> 184   _, created_layers = _create_keras_history_helper(tensors, set(), [])
    185   return created_layers
    186 

/root/anaconda3/envs/TensorPy36/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py in _create_keras_history_helper(tensors, processed_ops, created_layers)
    208     if getattr(tensor, '_keras_history', None) is not None:
    209       continue
--> 210     op = tensor.op  # The Op that created this Tensor.
    211     if op not in processed_ops:
    212       # Recursively set `_keras_history`.

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'op'
```

**Update**

I tried type cast X and Y_1 to the tensor objects as suggested in the comments. It is perfectly working in the case of Sequential API but failing for Fnctional API.

```
X_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(X, dtype=tf.float32) 
y_tensor=tf.convert_to_tensor(Y_1, dtype=tf.int32) 
model_lstm = Model(X_tensor,  y_tensor)
```

**Error**

**AttributeError: Tensor.op is meaningless when eager execution is enabled.**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-d090ea2b5a90> in <module>
----> 1 model_lstm = Model(X_tensor,  y_tensor)

/root/anaconda3/envs/TensorPy36/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    144 
    145   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 146     super(Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    147     _keras_api_gauge.get_cell('model').set(True)
    148     # initializing _distribution_strategy here since it is possible to call

/root/anaconda3/envs/TensorPy36/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    165         'inputs' in kwargs and 'outputs' in kwargs):
    166       # Graph network
--> 167       self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
    168     else:
    169       # Subclassed network

/root/anaconda3/envs/TensorPy36/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    456     try:
--> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    458     finally:
    459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/root/anaconda3/envs/TensorPy36/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in _init_graph_network(self, inputs, outputs, name, **kwargs)
    268 
    269     if any(not hasattr(tensor, '_keras_history') for tensor in self.outputs):
--> 270       base_layer_utils.create_keras_history(self._nested_outputs)
    271 
    272     self._base_init(name=name, **kwargs)

/root/anaconda3/envs/TensorPy36/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py in create_keras_history(tensors)
    182     keras_tensors: The Tensors found that came from a Keras Layer.
    183   """
--> 184   _, created_layers = _create_keras_history_helper(tensors, set(), [])
    185   return created_layers
    186 

/root/anaconda3/envs/TensorPy36/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py in _create_keras_history_helper(tensors, processed_ops, created_layers)
    208     if getattr(tensor, '_keras_history', None) is not None:
    209       continue
--> 210     op = tensor.op  # The Op that created this Tensor.
    211     if op not in processed_ops:
    212       # Recursively set `_keras_history`.

/root/anaconda3/envs/TensorPy36/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in op(self)
   1078   def op(self):
   1079     raise AttributeError(
-> 1080         "Tensor.op is meaningless when eager execution is enabled.")
   1081 
   1082   @property

AttributeError: Tensor.op is meaningless when eager execution is enabled.
```

Comment: What don't you understand?  It's saying you gave it (possibly the `X`) a `numpy` array, when it expected something else (a `tensor`?).  You have the `tensorflow` documentation and code, I don't.

Comment: I tried converting it into a Tensor but it still is not running and throwing error. On the other hand it is working perfectly fine for sequential API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a mistake in the code itself while executing the Model part of in the functional API version.

```
model_lstm = Model(inputs=X, outputs = Y_1)
```

I have given the variables inside the above part of the code only!! While in this part we just define what our model is going to be. Hence Here we will just write what is our input layer that needs to be considered and what will be my output layer here!! Input layer while constructing my model will be **input_layer** in the code and output layer will be **output_1**. Hence code should be

```
model_lstm = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs = output_1)
```

and after that we can do

```
model_lstm.fit(X,Y_1)
```

This will work perfectly fine now!!